# Call by reference a Java applet function from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript

When I call a Java applet function by reference from JavaScript code, it doesn't work correctly. The signatures are as stated below:

```
// Java Code:
public class  A extends Applet{

    public void foo(int[] a)
    {
        a[0]=3;
    }
}

//Javascript Code:
var arg = new Array(1);
arg[0]=2;
Applet.foo(arg);
```

But `arg[0]` remains `2`. Is it possible to call Java functions by reference from JavaScript?

My guess: I think because Java takes memory on JVM, it is not possible.

Comment: Careful: "call by reference" is a very specific term and neither Java nor JavaScript supports this. Both languages are "call (pass) by value" and in case of objects, the value is a reference to the object. More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy.

Comment: yes, you're right. I know that in java everything is passed by value. But this works when we have 2 Java functions or 2 java script functions. But the problem is that it doesn't work correctly when one of them is Java and the other is javascript